# Error in lsoda(y, times, func, parms, ...) : illegal input detected before taking any integration steps - see written message

Tags: r, optimization, ode

I am using code from https://rpubs.com/choisy/sir to estimate and optimize parameters in a SIR and SEIR model.

I had no trouble for the SIR model, but when I changed it to a SEIR model, I ran into some problems.

For data the flu data in R can be used. My data looks like this

```
    Date NewPositive NotPrevPos PosPct PrevPos Tested Tested_kumulativ
157  157          12      17516    0.1      99  17615        1.082.400
158  158          15      15294    0.1      67  15361        1.097.761
159  159          19      14254    0.1      67  14321        1.112.082
160  160          13       9574    0.1      50   9624        1.121.706
161  161          11       9700    0.1      37   9737        1.131.443
162  162           9      17759    0.1      82  17841        1.149.284
```

I use "Date" and "NewPositive" colums, which is similar to flu data.

The specific code I am using is

```
seir <- function(beta, lambda, gamma, S0, E0, I0, R0, times) {
  require(deSolve) # for the "ode" function
  
  # the differential equations:
  sir_equations <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
    with(as.list(c(variables, parameters)), {
      dS <- -beta * I * S
      dE <- beta * I * S - lambda * E
      dI <- lambda * E - gamma * I
      dR <- gamma * I
      return(list(c(dS, dE, dI, dR)))
    })
  }
  
  # the parameters values:
  parameters_values <- c(beta = beta ,lambda = lambda, gamma = gamma)
  
  # the initial values of variables:
  initial_values <- c(S = S0, E = E0, I = I0, R = R0)
  
  # solving
  out <- ode(initial_values, times, sir_equations, parameters_values)
  
  # returning the output:
  as.data.frame(out)
}



   # sum of squares function, i.e. the function we wanna optimize
ss <- function(beta, lambda, gamma, data = Infected, N = PopulationOfDenmark) {
  I0 <- 1
  times <- data$Date
  predictions <- seir(beta = beta, lambda = lambda, gamma = gamma,   # parameters
                      S0 = N - I0, E0 = 0, I0 = I0, R0 = 0, # variables' intial values
                      times = times)                # time points
  sum((predictions$I[-1] - data$NewPositive[-1])^2)
}



ss2 <- function(x) {  # Function around this ss() that will have an input interface that fits 
                       # the requirement of the optim() function
  ss(beta = x[1], lambda = x[2], gamma = x[3])
}



starting_param_val <- c(0.0002, 0.000005, 0.01)
ss_optim <- optim(starting_param_val, ss2)
ss_optim
```

I use the `deSolve` package, my RStudio version is 1.3.1073, and my OS is macOS 10.15.6 (19G2021).
The R functions I use are `ode()` and `optim()`.

When I try to run this, with the parameters here *beta = 0.0002, lambda = 0.000005, gamma = 0.01*, I get the error:

```
Error in lsoda(y, times, func, parms, ...) : 
  illegal input detected before taking any integration steps - see written message
```

Which has the traceback

```
7. lsoda(y, times, func, parms, ...) 
6. ode(initial_values, times, sir_equations, parameters_values) 
5. seir(beta = beta, lambda = lambda, gamma = gamma, S0 = N - I0, 
     E0 = 0, I0 = I0, R0 = 0, times = times) 
4. ss(beta = x[1], lambda = x[2], gamma = x[3]) 
3. fn(par, ...) 
2. (function (par) 
   fn(par, ...))(c(-0.000355555555555555, -0.000661666666666667, 
   0.0111111111111111)) 
1. optim(starting_param_val, ss2)
```

And the output I get from `optim()` are negative parameters.

Also I get an error like this, that continues

```
DLSODA-  Warning..Internal T (=R1) and H (=R2) are
      such that in the machine, T + H = T on the next step  
     (H = step size). Solver will continue anyway.
In above message, R1 = 165.348, R2 = 1.3052e-14
.
.
.
```

Which does not make a lot of sense to me.

The things I tried to fix the problem was changing the parameters I feed `optim()`.
I also tried to use for example `alpha = log(gamma)`, then using `alpha` in the `ss` and `ss2` function, `exp(alpha)` in the `seir` funtion, and `log(gamma parameter)` in `optim()` in stead of `gamma`.

I am very new to Stack, so please let me know, what I could do better, if this question is not in the right form.

Answer (score 1):

The system is non-linear. If it leaves the region of bounded behavior, that is, all parameters positive and all variables positive, quadratic positive feed-back tends to explode to infinity inside the integration interval. At such a singularity the step size control algorithm will reduce the step size further and further, until the reported error occurs, the step update does no longer advance the integration time.

In a similar situation I had partial success by forcing the positivity of the parameters, either by having them be squares, `beta=rt_beta^2`, or exponentials, `beta=exp(ln_beta)` etc., so that `ln_beta` can be unrestricted. This usually guarantees that the optimization returns a result, but not that the result is in any way meaningful.

Comment: This [excellent blog post of Martijn Weterings](https://blog.ephorie.de/contagiousness-of-covid-19-part-i-improvements-of-mathematical-fitting-guest-post) discusses some numerical difficulties of fitting SIR models. He also states that "COVID-19" is "a data epidemic". This was also the reason why I then stopped with this, but you can still find some models, links and **link lists** in my github repo. https://github.com/tpetzoldt/covid

Comment: @tpetzoldt : It is even worse, the numbers that are collected by the pharma lobby and state media are not even data, as there is no common (or) scientific standard behind their construction. Tests are not validated against a gold standard, there is no test to actually prove a virus infection, even from inside the PCR industry the application of the tests is fraudulent (Ct 40 or 55 when everything above 25 is meaningless), as even the WHO and Fauci have admitted in rare moments of truth.

Comment: I would definitely not go so far to call it fraudulent as @Lutz Lehmann, but I agree completely that there is considerable uncertainty in the data. I think we agree both, that modelling Covid and Flu data is quite difficult, so I wonder why so many people try it ;-)

All these uncertainties were already discussed in April 2020. At that time I was curious myself and wanted to understand what happens, so I got in contact to some epidemiological modellers and epidemiologists, but then I had other things to do and there have been enough people who deal with this topic.